# Changing title of shinyjs alert in R

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs

I am building a R shiny app and am using the `shinyjs::alert` function to let users know when a submission is successful. The default header for the pop-up is a 127 IP address. Can this be changed to a string of different text? Ideally the name of my organization would be used in its place.

The code below is swiped from the `shinyjs::alert` documentation with minor edits to create a button that sends the message "Hello World!" as an popup.

[image]

```
if (interactive()) {
  library(shiny)
  library(shinyjs)
  shinyApp(
    ui = fluidPage(
      useShinyjs(),  # Set up shinyjs
      actionButton("btn", "Click me")
    ),
    server = function(input, output) {
      observeEvent(input$btn, {
        # Change the following line for more examples
        alert("Hello world!")
      })
    }
  )
}
```

**Edit:**
When run on a windows OS on microsoft edge the default message appears as

[image]

Comment: Have you checked it with your browser? For me, in Firefox and Edge, no title is shown at all.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an external package for this:

- shinyalert: https://daattali.com/shiny/shinyalert-demo/
- shinyWidgets: https://github.com/dreamRs/shinyWidgets#sweet-alert

Answer (score 0):

When I run your code in Linux (on Firefox) this is how it looks:

[image: screnshot]

Maybe the window title is coming from your browser / operating system?